# MongoDB: How can I assign some value to a reference?

Tags: mongodb

Like this:

```
{_id:"Math", "takenBy":[{{$ref:"Student",$id:"Dennis"}, "mark":"88"}, {{$ref:"Student",$id:"Jack"}, "mark":"57"}]
```

which means both Dennis and Jack took the course Math, and Dennis got 88, while Jack only got 57.

Comment: By the way: lots of references to other documents are an anti-pattern in MongoDB and should be avoided when possible. MongoDB is different from relational databases in that regard. In relational databases, JOINs on declared foreign keys are quite cheap, but MongoDB doesn't even have JOINs.

Comment: @Philipp thanks, it's a performance comparison between MongodB and some other relational database.

Comment: When you try to use MongoDB as if it were a relational database, you will be disappointed by its performance. *"If you judge a fish by its ability to climb a tree, it will live its whole life believing that it is stupid."* (commonly attributed to Albert Einstein)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

It seems that I've forgotten to assign a key to the reference.

```
{_id:"Math", "takenBy":[{"student":{$ref:"Student",$id:"Dennis"}, "mark":"88"}, {"student":{$ref:"Student",$id:"Jack"}, "mark":"57"}]}
```